# cannot find a constructor for class org.apache.htrace.impl.ZipkinSpanReceiver which takes an HTraceConfiguration

Tags: zipkin, htrace

This is what i see in my HBase logs after following the instructions in this document:

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#tracing

```
2017-03-02 09:47:12,851 ERROR [main] htrace.SpanReceiverBuilder: SpanReceiverBuilder cannot find a constructor for class org.apache.htrace.impl.ZipkinSpanReceiverwhich takes an HTraceConfiguration.  Disabling span receiver.
```

Here's my entry in hbase-site.xml:

```
   <property>
      <name>hbase.trace.spanreceiver.classes</name>
      <value>org.apache.htrace.impl.ZipkinSpanReceiver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.htrace.zipkin.collector-hostname</name>
      <value>jesaremi-svpc</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.htrace.zipkin.collector-port</name>
      <value>9410</value>
    </property>
```

and I have the following additional jar files in the HBase Lib folder:

```
zipkin-1.20.1.jar
htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
htrace-zipkin-4.2.0-incubating.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

HTraceConfiguration package names are different.

(org.apache.htrace.HTraceConfiguration -> htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar)
(org.apache.htrace.**core**.HTraceConfiguration -> htrace-zipkin-4.2.0-incubating.jar)

I solved the problem using htrace-zipkin version 3.1.0.